# How to pass custom parameters to PHP from Nginx?

Tags: php, nginx, fastcgi, php-fpm

I'm using `Nginx 1.2.4` in combination with `PHP-FPM 5.4.8` with a `fastcgi` pass and trying to pass custom parameters to `PHP`. Here are the options I have found so far:

- using the `env` directive to set an environment variable in `nginx` and fetch it with `getenv()` or `$_ENV` from `PHP`. The problem is that `env` only operates in [`main` context](http://wiki.nginx.org/CoreModule#env) whereas I need to set the parameter in `server` context.
- using the `fastcgi_param` directive as it's designed for that.

I have tried changing the values of some parameters using `fastcgi_param` but was unsuccessful:

**nginx:**

```
fastcgi_param PATH_INFO "/var/tmp";
```

**PHP:**

I checked all the predefined arrays I could find:

```
echo '<pre>';
echo "\n".'$GLOBALS'."\n"; var_dump($GLOBALS);
echo "\n".'$_SERVER'."\n"; var_dump($_SERVER);
echo "\n".'$_GET'."\n"; var_dump($_GET);
echo "\n".'$_POST'."\n"; var_dump($_POST);
echo "\n".'$_FILES'."\n"; var_dump($_FILES);
echo "\n".'$_REQUEST'."\n"; var_dump($_REQUEST);
echo "\n".'$_SESSION'."\n"; var_dump($_SESSION);
echo "\n".'$_ENV'."\n"; var_dump($_ENV);
echo "\n".'$_COOKIE'."\n"; var_dump($_COOKIE);
echo "\n".'$php_errormsg'."\n"; var_dump($php_errormsg);
echo "\n".'$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA'."\n"; var_dump($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA);
echo "\n".'$http_response_header'."\n"; var_dump($http_response_header);
echo "\n".'$argc'."\n"; var_dump($argc);
echo "\n".'$argv'."\n"; var_dump($argv);
echo '</pre>';
```

The only one to show `PATH_INFO` was `$_SERVER`:

```
var_dump($_SERVER); // ["PATH_INFO"]=> string(0) ""
```

But the value I set in `nginx` isn't taken into account.

**Q1: Do I need to configure anything at `nginx/php` level for the `fastcgi_param` directive to take effect?**

**Q2: Is the `fastcgi_param` directive limited to a predefined list of parameters (e.g. I can set `PATH_INFO` but not custom variables of my own such as `FOO`)?**

**Q3: If yes to Q2: is there a way to pass custom parameters to PHP from Nginx?**

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can pass additional parameters via fastcgi_param directive. I'm sure because I used this funcionality.

My exemplary nginx config

```
server {
    server_name localhost;
    include     conf/defaults.conf;
    root        /var/www;

    location    ~* "\.php$" {
        fastcgi_param CRS "crs";
        include conf/fastcgi-php.conf;
    }                                           
}
```

And part of phpinfo() output:

```
...
_SERVER["USER"] fcgi
_SERVER["HOME"] /dev/null
_SERVER["FCGI_ROLE"]    RESPONDER
_SERVER["REMOTE_USER"]  no value
_SERVER["CRS"]  crs
_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"] no value
```

Comment: I have `fastcgi.conf` and `fastcgi_params` but not `fastcgi-php.conf`: where did you get it from? Do you mind sharing it via pastebin?

Comment: It's my specific config but there's no magic:

`fastcgi_pass    127.0.0.1:1028;`
`fastcgi_index   index.php;`
`include         conf/fastcgi.conf;`

and conf/fastcgi.conf contains rest of fastcgi required params and settings

Comment: The only thing I could think of is that I  forgot to include something in the conf when compiling `nginx`. On the other hand, I've forgotten to include things when compiling `nginx` in the past, but `nginx` would refuse to start saying it didn't know about some directives I was using: here nothing, no complaints, but yet that `fastcgi_param` isn't working :( I'll give a try to the original `ubuntu nginx` package and see how it goes.

Comment: Yes, it's working with the default `ubuntu nginx` package...

Comment: @user64204 this definitely was a problem with your configuration, and ubuntu package just overwritten some of your config files. But since you did not show to us your full configuration, there's no way to determine what the problem actually was.

Comment: I fixed it. Nothing wrong with my compiled Nginx, just another stupid mistake (there was another fastcgi location which I was convinced was not being applied but actually was, and that one was not using `fastcgi_param`, hence parameters not being set... :(

Answer (score 1):

You can modify the request by passing your custom variables in the request header, example:

```
proxy_set_header Variable-name-here Value-here;
```

And then you can read those values from the request header in your PHP script.